# superset-init-db "some pods failed" when trying to install via helm for GKE cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, apache-superset

Following [these instructions](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/running-on-kubernetes) for installing superset on GKE kubernetes cluster. But I keep getting error: `superset-init-db "some pods failed"` as can be seen here:

[image]

If I check the logs of the `superset-init-db` I see this:

```
UserWarning: Using the in-memory storage for tracking rate limits as no storage was explicitly specified. 

This is not recommended for production use. 

See: https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io#configuring-a-storage-backend for documentation about configuring the storage backend.
```

I have tried setting the service of superset as NodePort, LoadBalancer and even ClusterIP but keep getting same errors.

I read in some github issues to try setting HTTPS in the cluster all my services are currently in https but not superset because it just not recognized by GCP load balancer as healthy. Not sure what else to try.

## Update

So I never solved this issue but was able to workaround it by. It seems superset and istio service mesh don't work well together so I moved superset out of istio's namespace and then it worked. Not a solution but hope it helps someone else in future

Comment: If you are using a custom values.yaml file, you need to create another user, like Admin with caps, so you just need to replace this variable {{ .Values.init.adminUser.username }} with Admin, instead of admin

Comment: hey  @Hackerman thanks, that solved the admin error but still get the other error: `UserWarning: Using the in-memory storage for tracking rate limits as no storage was explicitly specified. This is not recommended for production use. See: https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io#configuring-a-storage-backend for documentation about configuring the storage backend.`

Comment: That is just a warning, superset should be running ok now. And for the warning, just read the doc and configure a storage backend if you want to use it for production